# Do SelectLists belong in viewModels?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

After reading this question 
[ASP.NET MVC: Nesting ViewModels within each other, antipattern or no?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623414/asp-net-mvc-nesting-viewmodels-within-each-other-antipattern-or-no)

and Derick Bailey's comment

> i think the "consider what your viewmodel would look like as xml or
>   json" bit is probably the most important point, here. i often use that
>   perspective to help me understand what the view model should look
>   like, and to help me understand what data is "viewmodel" data vs "data
>   that goes on the HTML rendering of the view". helps to keep things
>   clean  and separate them nicely – Derick Bailey Apr 11 '11 at 15:45

It makes me wonder how I would approach creating a View for a ViewModel with databound selection items.  I'm really struggling because I can't envision where the `SelectList` belongs.  If I think in terms of JSON or XML then the `SelectList` is part of the View Only.  All I want is a dropdown list prepopulated with a list of values for the user to select the `Location`  Having it in the ViewModel seems wrong, but when I think about moving it to the View I don't know where to place the logic to pull from the DB to populate the Selection List

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public int? page { get; set; }
    public int? size { get; set; }
    //Land Related search criteria        
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public SelectList LocationSelection{ get; set; }
```

### update

Here is a great question and answer that is really closely related
[C# mvc 3 using selectlist with selected value in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579598/c-sharp-mvc-3-using-selectlist-with-selected-value-in-view)

I've tested this implementation and it does what I think I want to do.  I'm not going to rush to pick an answer as I still haven't fully vetted this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refactor your viewModel along the following lines as I don't believe that selectlists should belong in the viewmodel:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public int? page { get; set; }
    public int? size { get; set; }
    //Land Related search criteria        
    public IEnumerable<Location> LocationSelection{ get; set; }
}
```

and in your view, populate the viewModel as such:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    var viewModel = new SearchViewModel()
    {
        viewModel.LocationSelection = _repository.All<Location>()
    };

    // any other logic here or in service class
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

then in your view, you'd use the html.dropdownlist helper to display your items.
works for me

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid SelectLists, as they do not seem to fit well into the MVC model.  Instead I create helpers to generate my HTML elements from `IEnumerable` types in the model.  I think this maintains the general rule of keeping the pure data in the model, and the display logic in the view.

But that's just my personal take.  I think creating SelectLists for the express purpose of displaying data in the view is silly.